# How to get all Travis CI environment variables, excluding the system defaults?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I want to pass into `docker run` all the environment variables I've configured in the Travis web UI.

I'm able to run `env > .env` to save them to a file and then pass that into docker via `--env-file .env`.

Unfortunately, this also overrides system ones such as `PATH` that interfere with the container.

I'm able to filter out `PATH` using `env | grep -vE "^(PATH=)" > .env` but I'm wondering whether there's a way to get just the Travis ones?

Here's my .travis.yml:

```
language: bash
sudo: required
services:
  - docker
before_install:
  - env | grep -vE "^(PATH=)" > .env
install:
  - docker build -t mycompany/myapp .
script:
  - docker run -i --env-file .env mycompany/myapp nosetests
after_success:
  - echo "SUCCESS!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend passing *all* your environment vars, but if you whitelist them by prefixing them with something like, say, `TRAVIS_` you could do something like:

```
export TRAVIS_WUT=foo
export TRAVIS_FOO=asdf
docker run $(printenv | grep -E '^TRAVIS_' | sed 's/TRAVIS_/-e /g')
  # would run -> docker run -e FOO=asdf -e WUT=foo something
```